# Restarting my PC more than once will hurt my SSD & other componets?

Tags: ssd, fan, reboot

Does anyone know if I restart my PC once, twice, or even more in one day hurt my SSD and shorten the lifespan of it just like how it may shorten the life of an HDD since it puts stress on the moving parts of the HDD.

I'm doing the restart from the start menu,I'm not doing a force shutdown or force reset. Even though I'm using this method can it also shorten the lifespan of the fans such as case fans, CPU cooler, GPU fans, and PSU fans?

If you can provide me with any information that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any sources or links to back this up, but since some people restart 20+ times per day for various reasons without issues, I don't see how restarted a couple times a day would make any noticeable change in the life of your hardware.

Answer (score 4):

Like you said, SSDs don't have moving parts so they don't wear down from moving arms and gears like HDDs. Instead, the wearing comes from writing data only, not from both reading and writing. Turning your computer off and on will cause a little writing but definitely nothing to worry about when compared to all the other mechanical parts in your computer. That doesn't mean something else will break instead, just that there are a lot of other parts to consider instead of a SSD. I haven't had my two SSDs go bad yet and one of them has had a good amount of writing on it and I always turn off my computer if I know I won't be using it for more than an hour or so. I like to save power and wear on my components.

Here is some good info about what's going on under the hood:
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-ssds-solid-state-drives-work-increase-lifespan/

There are some people doing research into how much data can be written on some SSDs before failure and the amounts are huge. Nothing a normal consumer will need to worry about. 
https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead

EDIT: I forgot the 2nd part of the question. There will be wear to the mechanical components regardless of how you turn off your computer and then powering it back on but I wouldn't worry about it unless you do it many, many times a day. I usually keep my components for at least a few years, sometimes a bit longer depending on the part and whether I want to upgrade to the latest-and-greatest and I've only had one fan die on me on a video card once. It was time for a new card anyway.